# java upgrade on weblogic

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, jdk1.7

I want to upgrade java on weblogic `10.3.4.0` form `jdk1.6` to `jdk1.7`.
I have downloaded java and and set `JAVA_HOME` variable in following files:

- nodemanager.properties
- setDomainEnv.sh
- commEnv.sh
- bsu.sh

But after restart of admin and all managed servers it is showing only node manager is running on `jdk1.7`, rest all managed servers are still running on `jdk1.6`. Please suggest what else changes I need to do in order to upgrade java on managed servers as well.

Answer (score 0):

`WebLogic Server` version `10.3.x` is started to be called as `Weblogic 11g` after `Oracle` purchased from the former firm. For Installations prior to `Weblogic Server version 10.3.6`, you can not use `jdk1.7` but `jdk1.6`. That is, you need to install at least `10.3.6` to be able to use `jdk1.7`.

By the way, you need to use `JRockit` instead of `JDK` for production systems.